# Composer Only Installs Packages w/ Manual Update to JSON File

Tags: php, composer-php

When I use composer to install packages in my project I am only able to do so if I update my json file manually.

For example, if I run the following command in Git-Bash in my project directory (which contains my composer.phar and composer.json file):

```
php composer.phar require php-di/slim-bridge
```

It returns the following error:

> [Invalid Argument Exception]
>   Could not find package
>   php-di\slim-bridge at any version for your minimum-stability (stable).
>   Check the package spelling or your minimum stability.

However, if i were to just update my json file to the following (example I've provided contains multiple packages I am using in my project):

```
{
    "require": {
      "slim/slim": "^3.0",
      "slim/twig-view": "^2.1",
      "illuminate/database": "^5.2",
      "respect/validation": "^1.0",
      "slim/csrf": "^0.6",
      "slim/flash": "^0.1",
      "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
      "php-di/slim-bridge":"^1.0"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app"
        }
    }
}
```

... And I run the command: `$ php.composer.phar update`

Everything installs to project correctly.

What is going on that I am not able to install packages using the require method thus making me resort to manually updating my json file each time?

Comment: Dumb question here: I noticed in the error message there's a backslash (\\) between php-di and slim-bridge. Is that what you used when you ran the command? When I run the command with a backslash, I get the exact same error. But when I change it to a forward slash (/), it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that backslash looks very suspicious to me, too.

Comment: I know it seems odd myself. But I can verify that it was run with forward (/)

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using windows, I used the windows installer for composer rather than install through command line and I got this working correctly. Much much easier now since I don't have to update my JSON files manually.